# Regrouping multiple polygon with same attributes in one in QGIS

Tags: polygon, merge, qgis-2, dissolve

In QGIS 2.14 I have a polygon shapefile with thousands of entities (=row) and > 10 attribute column.

A lot of these polygons share the exact same attributes, in fact there is only 12 different types of polygons.

I want to regroup all polygons with sames attributes in only one (so I just want to have 12 entities at the end and keep all the attribute data).

I have tried lots of options "regroup", "dissolve", "dissolve by attribute", etc... but each time one of these issues occurs :

- I lost lot of columns (just keeping 1 or 2/3);
- I got just one entity;
- Some polygons "disappear"

The closest I found was SAGA "Dissolve", but it don't process on all polygons.

Any idea?

Comment: In QGIS 3.4, the `Dissolve` tool allows you to dissolve based on multiple attribute fields, which would achieve what you need. I don't remember if it had this feature in 2.14.

Comment: Does any of the tools combine the geometries the way you want (forget about the attributes here, I'm just asking about the polygons)? If so, take that output and do a spatial join (`join attributes by location` tool) with the original to get the attributes back.

Comment: Hello, yes, the "dissolve" option works great but it didn't take every polygon into account, and i can't found a legit reason why :(

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it works on 2.14 as well but in my QGIS you can:

- open attribute table
- sort or filter the column you want to regroup
- mark all rows that you want to regroup
- right click the layer in your layer table while having objects still marked
- click Export --> Export Chosen objects only
- save as new layer

Not sure about the precise phrasing, because my QGIS is not in English. Hope it still helps.

Comment: Hello! ty for your answer but i need all polygons on the same layer. Can be worth to try to fuse them after separating them still. gonna try that.